# What is disadvantage of using 255.255.255.255?

Tags: broadcast

I used 255.255.255.255 as local network broadcast address, but some say using that address for broadcast is 'bad idea'. And suggest to use subnet(or NAT) broadcast address something like 192.168.1.255

But I couldn't find any reason for that. Please tell me any difference between them or any disadvantage of using 255.255.255.255!

Comment: Belongs to superuser

Comment: @JleruOHeP wow I didn't know that site. Thanks a lot!